# Storing byte array in HTML5 sqlite database

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, html

I am working on an offline capable mobile web app and need to store large amounts of raw byte data in a HTML5 database.  I want to store them as compact as possible, so a joined string is not an option. Here is a sample code that creates a db, table, inserts data and retrieves it again.

Example:

```
var bytes=[97, 0, 6, 244, 98, 66, 76, 65, 131, 5, 7, 142, 81, 184, 112, 33];

openDatabase('_test_', 1.0, '_test-', 5000).transaction(function(tx) {
tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MYTABLE", [], function(){
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE(content BLOB);",[],function(){
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO MYTABLE values(?)", [bytes], 
    function()
    {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE ", [], function(transaction, results)
        {
            console.log(results.rows.item(0))
        });
},function(transaction, error){console.log(error)})
},function(transaction, error){console.log(error)})
})
})
```

I am  trying to store the array as is, which actually saves as a joined string :"97, 0, 6, 244, 98, 66, 76, 65, 131, 5, 7, 142, 81, 184, 112, 33". Not what I need since it will be way too large.

I am converting the array into a string now:

```
openDatabase('_test_', 1.0, '_test-', 5000).transaction(function(tx) {
tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MYTABLE", [], function(){
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE(content BLOB); ", [], function(){
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO MYTABLE values(?)", [s], 
    function()
    {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE ", [], function(transaction, results)
        {
            console.log(results.rows.item(0))
        });
},function(transaction, error){console.log(error)})
},function(transaction, error){console.log(error)})
})
})
```

What the DB now returns is simply "a".

So my question is how do I serialize a javascript byte array in HTML5 database without resorting to a joined string?

Comment: Why do you have `'0' in your array, which is a null character?

Comment: the data simply contains a byte with the value 0. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Convert data to hexadecimal values and insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(X'53514C697465');
```

> BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and preceded by a single "x" or "X" character

[Literal Values](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Comment: How can I do that for a DB column that is supposed to hold more then one byte? I need to encode a sequence of bytes.

Comment: So for [97, 256, 6, 244, 98, 66, 76, 65, 131, 5, 7, 142, 81, 184, 112, 33] I am inserting X'611006F462424C4183578E51B87021' as its hex representation. I am not clear on how to cast the value from a select to the original javascript array again. Could you help here as well?

Comment: Assuming SQLite returns a hexadecimal string that looks like `"611006F462424C4183578E51B87021"`, you can iterate every two characters, slice, parseInt and push onto an array. Since every two characters represents a byte, just write a `for` loop that increase the index by 2 every time instead of by 1. You can grab the two characters via String.slice(), like so: `hex.slice(ix, ix+2)`. You can convert these to an integer via `parseInt(str, 16)`. So it would look like: `arr = []; for(var ix = 0; ix < hex.length; ix = ix+2) { arr.push(parseInt(hex.slice(ix, ix+2), 16)); }`

Comment: This answer has not been upvoted once the past 8 years?