# Java byteArray equivalent in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, byte, arrays

I am trying to determine what encoding scheme will give me the numbers -1 or -40 (the starting numbers for the file) for a jpeg file type.

A rest api I'm working on is expecting a byte array that looks like [-1, 94, 43, 34, etc]. In node.js I can have the byte array as hex, or any other encoding type, but I seem not able to get -1 or -40 for the starting value whichever encoding scheme I try.

In the documentation I saw an example in Java which uses the "toByteArray()" function, which seems to get the starting values (-1 or -40). Can anyone help me?

Comment: See typed arrays? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12332802/461499

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you can use [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) to get file contents, then read the bytes from it into your array.

Java `byte` type is a signed 8-bit integer, the equivalent in Node.js Buffer is `buf.readInt8()`.

So you can read the required amount of `byte`s from `Buffer` into your array using `buf.readInt8()`

Or just convert it into `Int8Array`:

```
new Int8Array(new Buffer([100, 200, 255, 1, 32]));
```

Comment: Hi zulmer thnxs for the response, so the value passed to the Buffer object would it be the size of the file  var buf = new Buffer(filesize). Also for readInt8(offset), the offset value should be 0?

Comment: If you need to get jpeg file contents, use [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module, more specifically `fs.readFile()` or `fs.readFileSync`. It will provide you with `Buffer` with file contents. `offset` is the amount of bytes to skip, e.g. `offset=0` will return the first byte, `offset=1` will return the second byte, etc.

Comment: perfect readInt8() does give the expected byte when offset is set to 0, how can get all the byte values with this function do i just set readInt8(0, true), not sure about this

Comment: to rephrase the above comment, i can run a loop to get all the byte values but is there a function that just returns all the values

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`TypeArray.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from) method on all [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) to convert between normal arrays:

```js
const values = [-1, 94, 43, 34]

const byteArr = Int8Array.from(values)
const original = Array.from(byteArr)

console.log({ byteArr, original })
```

**Bonus**: This works in node *and also* the browser

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). It allows reading/writing of variously sized binary values and random access.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to change the logic of identifying a JPEG file using magic numbers from the first 4 bytes, your -40 logic could be insufficient.

```
FFD8FFE0 should be the first 4 bytes of a jpeg file
```

Therefore following Node.js program could be helpful

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.open("c:\\aa1.jpg", 'r', function(err, doc){
    var check = "FFD8FFE0";
    var headerLength = ( check.length / 2 );

    var byteBuffer = new Buffer(headerLength);
    for(var i=0;i<headerLength;i++)
      byteBuffer[i] = 0x00;

    var head = "";

    fs.read(doc, byteBuffer, 0, headerLength, 0, function(err, num) {
      for(var i=0;i<headerLength;i++)
        head += byteBuffer[i].toString(16);

      if(head.toLowerCase() == check.toLowerCase())
        console.log('It is a JPEG file');
      else
        console.log('It is not a JPEG file');
    });
});
```

check for err and doc null check is not included in this program

Refer [How to identify contents of a byte[] is a jpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550296/how-to-identify-contents-of-a-byte-is-a-jpeg)