# Cast int array as byte array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typing

I'm trying to take an array of integers and cast it to bytes in JavaScript but can't quite figure out how to do it.

The input would look something like [2,-76,7,2,8,69,82,88,87,2,52,50,...].

If I was going to do it in another language like Java I'd use something like the following.

```java
byte[] bytArr = new byte[intArray.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.size(); i++) {
      bytArr[i] = (byte) intArray[i];
}
```

I'm pretty new to JS so not sure if this is even possible...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java byteArray equivalent in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797862/java-bytearray-equivalent-in-javascript)

Comment: JS isn't typed.

Comment: What would be the purpose? JavaScript does have optimized integer array types, but most of the time you just uses plain arrays of `Number`. Are you trying to save memory? Truncate off the high bytes? Something else?

Comment: @LoganDevine: JS isn't *statically* typed, and the typing system is more weak than not, but it is typed, and there are [special array types for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Int8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int8Array), which is a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

```
const arr = Int8Array.from([2,-76,7,2,8,69,82,88,87,2,52,50]);
```