# Make byte arrays (from files) in Node.js for use in Java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, node.js

I have a Node.js project that is going to make a call to a Java application using the NPM Java library. The Java app will be looking for images and PDFs in the form of byte arrays. Assuming I have some sort of blob or buffer on the Node side, is there a way to create a byte array usable by Java before passing it over?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332002/how-to-store-a-byte-array-in-javascript

Comment: That should be documented in the NPM Java library you mention. What's that library?