# Storing null bytes in Javascript string literals

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

Consider the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            const a = " ... ";

            for (let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
                console.log(a.charCodeAt(i));
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where the `...` in the string is actually the ASCII characters `NUL` (0), `SOH` (1), `STX` (2). This file is saved as UTF-8 (the only valid HTML5 encoding).

When I open it in Firefox or Chrome it prints this:

```
32
65533
1
2
32
```

However according to my reading of [the spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-literals-string-literals), I should be able to store a null byte:

```
StringLiteral ::
    " DoubleStringCharactersopt "
    ' SingleStringCharactersopt '

DoubleStringCharacters ::
    DoubleStringCharacter DoubleStringCharactersopt

DoubleStringCharacter ::
    SourceCharacter but not one of " or \ or LineTerminator
    <LS>
    <PS>
    \ EscapeSequence
    LineContinuation

SourceCharacter ::
    any Unicode code point
```

and

> All Unicode code point values from U+0000 to U+10FFFF, including surrogate code points, may occur in ECMAScript source text where permitted by the ECMAScript grammars.

So why won't it let me store a null byte?

(Yes I am aware of all the implications, please don't tell me that I shouldn't want to do this.)

Edit: to be clear the string is *not* `" \x00\x01\x02 "`. It is this:

[image: evil string]

Comment: What exactly does your string literal look like? I just made a string with character code 0 in it and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure it's UTF8 in this case? Because adding a meta for charset usually ensures this, and CSS doesnt do it by default so it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: @somethinghere: I tried adding `<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>`; made no difference.

Comment: @Pointy I update the questions; hopefully it should clarify things.

Comment: Well whatever's happening clearly has to do with how the lexer is dealing with the source code and those bytes. JavaScript strings (post-parsing) are UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: Obviously. I asked this question so I could find out why the lexer was not allowing this. See my answer for the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the Javascript to an external `.js` file then it does work fine, so this is a limitation of HTML, not Javascript.

Apparently HTML parsers will emit [an `unexpected-null-character` error](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-unexpected-null-character) and either ignore it or replace it with U+FFFD.

I believe the relevant state is [Script data state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#script-data-state) which explicitly calls out null bytes as being disallowed.

Answer (score -1):

I would not expect a text file to be able to carry the code point NUL at all (and also a couple of other control characters). This is also consistent with [no named character reference (aka entity) available for U+0000](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html). Most likely this is a precaution to not confuse (old) implementation dealing with [NUL-terminated strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).

Even enclosing your `<script>` part into [`<![CDATA[` in XHTML would not allow U+0000](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#cdata-section-state). But then again [XML itself doesn't allow U+0000](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets).

Separating HTML from JS is the best approach, but even then you might want to separate JS from binary data, too. Treating control characters as a `String` is questionable practice, too, since you cannot expect in which encoding that text will be interpreted - better use [byte arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12332002/4299358):

```js
var bytes= new Array( 0, 1, 2 );
```

Comment: Text files can contain null characters perfectly well. If you read my answer and the links within they state that it is specifically disallowed in HTML for security reasons (there's a lot of C code out there that doesn't deal with null bytes in strings properly).

Comment: "you cannot expect in which encoding that text will be interpreted" - yes you can; the only valid HTML5 character encoding is UTF-8, and you can even set that explicitly with a meta tag

Comment: Why do you conclude I haven't read all that? The docs only dictate - I come up with a potential reason. My point is that NUL in text files don't make sense. No, I mean the internal text encoding of JS, not the obvious one of your text file - JS implementations differ and may use UTF-16 or whatever on strings. Which is the point of not interchanging strings with bytes - one should only do that when it's 100% clear how it works under the hood. Also please edit comments instead of posting multiple in a row - this is not a chat.

Comment: "The docs only dictate" - they don't; they mention security reasons.

Comment: The encoding of JS strings is not an issue. Those are always UTF-16 (actually WTF-16 but it makes no difference in this case). They can store code points 0-255 with no problems.